# How PriorityQueue are ordered according to natural ordering

Tags: priority-queue

```
PriorityQueue<String> pq = new PriorityQueue<String>();
pq.add("banana");
pq.add("pear");
pq.add("apple");
System.out.println(pq);
     while(!pq.isEmpty())
     System.out.print(pq.poll()+" ");
```

Output is:-

```
[apple, pear, banana]
apple banana pear
```

How it is in Natural ordering. please explain it.
This question is from SCJP dum.

Answer (score 0):

Let us try Justifying Its name (Priority-Queue).

Priority-Queue, It says Put elements into the Queue retrieve based on its Priority.

**Add** – add an element to the queue with an associated priority.

**Poll** – remove the element from the queue that has the highest priority and return it.

**Peek** – look at the element with highest priority without removing it.

When using priorityQueue you should remember, when you are inserting elements into it using **add() or offer() it will only add your element into a it.**

**It will not guaranty you to return your elements in natural order.**

You need to **use peek() or poll(),**
If you want **to get the value in some predictable order** be it natural order or  by a Comparator provided at queue construction time, depending on which constructor is used.

**Hope This helps !!!!**